# Not Able to Loop up to the end of the Column in Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape through a column using **for loop** and rearrange the data into different categories. Let say the raw data have the name, address, email and phone number of the customer and it is separated by comma. I was able to create a simple script that will separate the information by comma, but it wont loop to the whole column A. The script will run up to 1654 of column A only.

I would like to ask if there is a limitation in looping through columns or row using Google App Script. Also, the data is consist of 3000 data, so that is 3000 cell in a column. Is there a way that we can loop up to the last data of my sheet?

```
function rawDataAlteration() {
  var days = new Array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Raw Data');
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var filteredData = new Array();
  for (let q in data) {
    if(data[q] != "") {
      filteredData.push(data[q]);
    }
  }
  for (let x in filteredData) {
    if (filteredData[x] != "") {
      var convertedToArray = filteredData[x][0].split(',');
      var nametoArray = convertedToArray[0].split(' ');
      var name = new Array();
      var day = "";
      var columnNum = Math.floor(x)+1;
      var nameColumn = 'A'+ columnNum;
      var dayColumn = 'B' + columnNum;
      var dateColumn = 'C' + columnNum;
      var shiftColumn = 'D' + columnNum;
      for(let i in nametoArray){
          let found = false;
          for(let j in days){
              if(nametoArray[i] == days[j]){
                  day = days[j];
                  found = true;
              }
          }
          if(!found){
              name.push(nametoArray[i]);
          }
      }
      var columnB = spreadsheet.getRange(nameColumn).setValue(name.toString().replace(',', ' '));
      var columnD = spreadsheet.getRange(dayColumn).setValue(day);
      var columnD = spreadsheet.getRange(dateColumn).setValue(convertedToArray[1]);
      // Logger.log(filteredData);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation for looping of rows or column but there is limitation for run time. The maximum run time is 6 mins, exceeding 6 mins will cause the script to fail. See [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

These are the factors that affect the run time of your code.

1. Having 3 nested for loops.
   Instead of using this to check if an element is present in days array:

> ```
> let found = false;
> for (let j in days) {
>   if (nametoArray[i] == days[j]) {
>     day = days[j];
>     found = true;
>   }
> }
> if (!found) {
>   name.push(nametoArray[i]);
> }
> ```

Use this:

> ```
>   if(days.indexOf(nametoArray[i]) >= 0){
>     day = days[j];
>   }else{
>     name.push(nametoArray[i]);
>   }
> ```

2. Using `A1:A` as range means that the script will get all the value in column A including the empty cells. Example, if you have 3000 data and 1000 empty space below it, `getValues()` will return 4000 sub-arrays or rows of data.

To ensure that you will only take the rows that has of data, change your code

**From:**

> ```
> var data = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
> ```

**To:**

> ```
> var data = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, spreadsheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
> ```

3.Instead of calling `setValue()` multiple times, Arrange the data into a single array and use `setValues()`. This will lessen your function call from 9000 to 1.

### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: I tried the script above, but it stops around 300+ cell.

Comment: @ian - How long is the run time of your script? Does it have errors?

Comment: @ian - Could share a sample spreadsheet and the expected output.